# General exception handling issue

Tags: c#, .net, exception, active-directory

I'm working with the Active Directory APIs, and am attempting to connect to the server using the following code:

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, (server + ":" + port), loginUsername, loginPassword);
```

Whenever an invalid login username or password are passed, an exception from the whole statement is not thrown, but the following code continues executing. On debugging, I have found that the `PrincipalContext` class however throws an error, as shown below:

[image]

Those are two properties contained within the class. On further examining the "ConnectedServer" property, the following is displayed in the debugger:

[image]

My problem is that since an error is not thrown externally, I am unsure of how to actually check for this error. I would like to show a simple error message if the username or password are invalid - basically finding a way to check if the above errors have been thrown.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes of `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` are differed execution. It does not attempt to connect to the Active Directory server till it has to. The [ValidateCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is the way to force a check, from the MSDN:

> The ValidateCredentials method binds to the server specified in the
>   constructor. If the username and password parameters are null, the
>   credentials specified in the constructor are validated. If no
>   credential were specified in the constructor, and the username and
>   password parameters are null, this method validates the default
>   credentials for the current principal.

So all you need to do is

```
using(PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, (server + ":" + port), loginUsername, loginPassword))
{
    //This will force the connection to the server and validate that the credentials are good
    //If the connection is good but the credentals are bad it will return "false", if the connection is bad it will throw a exception of some form.
    if(principalContext.ValidateCredentials(null, null))
    {
        // Rest of code here.

        //This is how you do the same check you where doing in your previous quesiton, notice that this is "userName", and "password" not "loginUsername" and "loginPassword"
        valid = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName,password);

    }
}
```

Comment: My main issue is that I don't only want to validate a username and password, but want to make sure that the respective account has the necessary credentials to connect to the Active Directory.

Comment: Kindly refer to my previous question to understand the context of what I'm trying to accomplish. I did not get any assistance over there, so am going about this by trial and error, as I cannot find any straightforward explanation online: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838249/how-to-run-application-in-an-authenticated-manner

Comment: Yes, that is what this does. If you get to `// Rest of code here` you have confirmed that both that 1) The server at `(server + ":" + port)` is responding and 2) the credentials `loginUsername, loginPassword` has the privileges to communicate with the server. So looking at your old question you would pass in that administrator's username and password in to `loginUsername` and `loginPassword`.

Comment: So would the `ValidateCredentials` method return false if the account being passed does not have enough credentials to access ActiveDirectory? The reason I am asking is because as part of the application which I am creating, I have created a method which validates user credentials - i.e. just checks if their username and password are correct. To do this, I am using the ValidateCredentials method - but the accounts can be any account stored in the AD database, so they could be accounts which have low rights. Would it not work in these cases? If so, is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Notice I am passing in `null, null` to ValidateCrediantals, that makes it validate the credentials you passed in to `PrincipalContext`. Yes those rights could be a user that does not have rights to do the operations you want to do (like create a new user or whatnot), the only thing you can do in that situation is put try-catch blocks around the things that fail when you attempt to do them with a user with insufficient rights, and when the failure happens display a nice dialog to the user saying they need to use a account with more privileges to complete that action.

Comment: Just checking if I've understood correctly. Is it possible to connect to the AD with an administrator account, and then be able to validate the credentials of any account I like (does not matter if they have low rights)?

Comment: Yes, see my update to see how to do it. I do not know about what rights they need to perform that check. I think the right to just connect to the server period is enough, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Hi again Scott - I have tried as you suggested, however ValidateCredentials(null,null) is returning true, even if invalid credentials are passed in the constructor, where the server is specified.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle any exception from the principal context is by placing your code in try and then catch the exceptions as shown below.

```
        string user = txtUsername.Text;
        string pass = txtPassword.Text;

        //start a try and catch method
      try
      {

       //create a principalcontext object

        var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "*****", user, pass);
         {


               //validate the user credentials
                if (pc.ValidateCredentials(user, pass))
                {
                    //create a user identity
                    UserPrincipal userp = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, user);

                    //check if the user is returned

                    if (userp != null)
                    {
                        //if user exists, return an array of authorized groups
                        var grps = userp.GetAuthorizationGroups();

                        //convert the array to a list to enable search of CIS group
                        List<string> strList = grps.Select(o => o == null ? String.Empty : o.ToString()).ToList();

                        //check for CIS group from the list
                        if (strList.Contains("CISS"))
                        {
                            //create a session variable to show the loggedin user and set the error panel to false
                            Session["username"] = user;
                            ErrorPanel.Visible = false;

                            //redirect the user to the homepage
                            Response.Redirect("appdesk/account.aspx");
                        }
                        else if (!strList.Contains("CISS"))
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "You Don't have the Rights to login to the platfrom";
                            ErrorPanel.Visible = true;

                    }
                }
                 //if the user credentials are invalid
                if (!pc.ValidateCredentials(user, pass))
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Login Failed.Incorrect Username or Password";
                    ErrorPanel.Visible = true;


                }
             }
        }
          //catch the exceptions in the try
       catch (Exception exc)
       {
                Label1.Text = exc.Message.ToString();
                ErrorPanel.Visible = true;                    

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic catch doesn't work?  Something like:

```
private ADConnectResults Connect(string server, int port)
try
{
    PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, (server + ":" + port), loginUsername, loginPassword);
    return new ADConnectResults(true, principalContext);
}
catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException dex)
{
     Log(dex);
     return new ADConnectResults(false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that attempting to assign the PrincipalContext.ConnectedServer property to a variable allowed the exception to surface:

```
using(var _ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, server + ":" + port))
{
   try
   {
      var connectedServer = _ctx.ConnectedServer;
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      //do something with the caught exception
   }
}
```